# How to keep a cat out of a crib / bassinet

Tags: cats, behavior, training, containment

My wife is 7 months pregnant and we've got most of our nursery area (it's in our master bedroom) set up.

Now, our 4 year old 18 lbs (8.2 kg) Maine Coon is getting up and sleeping in the baby's bassinet.

My wife is worried that he will hurt the baby once he arrives, scratch him or worse.

The cats currently sleep in our room on their cat tree. Their litter box and food are in our master bathroom. The cats have always had free run of our room and other furniture so how can I deter or prevent the cat from climbing in or on the new baby furniture?

Comment: Related sister site question [What are possible risks to a child's health from having an indoor cat?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/21805)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the one hand, there is a strong possibility that once the baby (noisy stinky thing that your cat will think it is) begins to occupy the bed, the cat will no longer want anything to do with the bed.  Also, your concerns about smothering are likely exaggerated.

On the other hand, you clearly should prevent this, and begin now, even if only for the sake of cleanliness of the baby's bed.

One option might be canned air.  I've taught my cat to keep off curio shelves by manually giving him a puff.  There are versions available that have a motion sensor on top as well.  Perhaps begin by placing one at the base, so the cat gets "shot" before he even gets as far as the bed.

Another option would be to place something in the bed, whenever the baby is not there, that the cat doesn't like.  Some people say their cats avoid those plastic floor protectors with the spikes on the under-side, if turned spikes up.  It doesn't work for me, but it might for you.

Comment: I'll look into the compressed air thing, I've currently laid some foil down inside the bassinet to hopefully scare him off.  I'm not real worried about it myself, my wife is and we all know... happy wife..happy life.

Comment: I think for now this is probably our best option, thank you, I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 4):

I would keep the door to the nursery closed at all times, so the cat cannot get in.  Start it now, while you're probably not in there that much, and the cat will get used to it, and hopefully be less interested in trying to get in there after the baby arrives.  If you're concerned that you won't hear the baby in the nursery with the door closed, make sure to get baby monitors.

Answer (score 3):

A friend of ours filled the crib with balloons or alikes to prevent the cat from getting in the crib.
Once the baby was there, the cat had no interest anymore in the crib.

A better idea would indeed be to simply keep the cat out of the baby's room by closing the door.
Health wise this would also be better for the baby
A house cat will quickly learn what area's of the house they can enter and which not.

We never let our cats in our bedroom and they never try to enter.
We occasionally let them in our office, but only when we are in there and they will only try to go in when the door is open and we are inside.